# How to set up Bibtex

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, bibliographies

after 4 hours of searching for answers and trying everything I could I need specific help. 
I write a report and I want to include a bibliography. I still get these error messages:

1. Empty bibliography
2. There were undefined references
3. Please (re)run
   BibTeX on the file(s):(biblatex) "Filename"(biblatex) and rerun LaTeX
   afterwards.
4. Citation 'Example Cite' on page 3 undefined*

My code looks like this:

```
    \documentclass[12pt, twoside]{report}
%Standard Packages
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{emptypage}
%\usepackage[round, authoryear]{natbib}
%\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{color}
\graphicspath{{Pictures/}}
\usepackage[a4paper,width=150mm,top=25mm,bottom=25mm,bindingoffset=6mm]{geometry}

% zusätzliche Schriftzeichen der American Mathematical Society
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}

%Library
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,bibencoding=ascii,style=authoryear,sorting=none]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bibfile.bib}

\begin{document}

%\bibliography{bibfile.bib}

\newpage
\thispagestyle{empty}
\include{01_abstract}

\setcounter{page}{1}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\include{02_dedication}

\include{03_declaration}

\include{04_acknowledges}
\newpage

\tableofcontents{}

\listoffigures{}
\listoftables{}
\newpage

\setcounter{page}{1}
\pagenumbering{arabic}

\Include{Chapter1}


\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

I also have a part of my bibfile:

```
@book{Fluid Mechanics Seventh Edition,
    author    = {Frank M. White},
    title     = {Fluid Mechanics, Seventh Edition},
    year      = {2011,
    publisher = {McGraw-Hill}
}
```

When I am using Quick Build to file the document: latex + Bibtex + 2x Latex + Viewpdf is executed.
What do I have to do to get the bibliography printed?
Thanks very much for helping!

Comment: Have you tried to use a `.bib` key without spaces? `@book{whitefluid,` for example. What does the `.blg` file say?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The .bib key must not contain spaces, and the opening brace of the year 
in your .bib file was not followed by a closing brace. With this 
file

```
@book{Fluid_Mechanics_Seventh_Edition,
   author    = {Frank M. White},
   title     = {Fluid Mechanics, Seventh Edition},
   year      = {2011},
   publisher = {McGraw-Hill}
```

}

and a

```
\cite{Fluid_Mechanics_Seventh_Edition}
```

in your LaTeX source, everything works fine on my box.